# Why can't I access public property field in static class

Tags: c#, .net, enums, static-classes

I'm trying to figure out why this is not working...

```
public static class ApplicationType
{
    private static ApplicationEnum application = ApplicationEnum.App1; 
    public static ApplicationEnum Application
    {
        get { return application; }
        set { application = value; }
    }

    public enum ApplicationEnum
    {
        App1,
        App2,
        App3
    }
}
```

I want to access `Application` from another class, such as...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ApplicationType.   //<-- Intellisense shows only ApplicationEnum    }
```

Thanks.

EDIT: Problem was that I was not trying inside the MainWindow as in this example as I thought I was.

Comment: @CL4PTR4P He doesn't have to, that's why he made it `static`. OP, is `MainWindow` inside the same project/assembly?

Comment: or if you want access ApplicationEnum type you should make it public

Comment: Your class wouldn't compile with "inconsistent accessibility" as error. Did you even read the compiler error? It's telling you exactly what's wrong. You can't have a public property on a public type that returns a private type.

Comment: ApplicationEnum is private ? why?

Comment: This won't compile because you're exposing a private type (`ApplicationEnum`) through a public accessor (`Application`)

Comment: @Dmitry Yes, If I make ApplicationEnum public, I can access it, but in this case I want public access to Application

Comment: @hagensoft Why do you want to refer to a property outside a method? Referring to properties is meaningful in a method body, but not in a class.

Comment: @hagensoft: If ApplicationEnum itself isn't public, your property won't compile. That's completely separate from the problem in MainWindow.

Comment: I have updated an changed the Enum to public.

Comment: but I want to access `Application`

Comment: @CodesInChaos I'm looking to access `Application`. I did a last minute change that produced an error that was published, but my point is accessing `Application`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're in the middle of a class declaration. You need to declare a field, method etc. For example, this should be fine (if you make `ApplicationEnum` public):

```
private ApplicationEnum foo = ApplicatoinType.Application;
```

Until you've made `ApplicationEnum` public, you'll find that your `Application` property will fail to compile - you can't declare a public property of a type which isn't itself public.

Comment: You have a typo in `ApplicationType.Application`, Jon.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the enum to public, but I still only have access to `ApplicationType.ApplicationEnum` but not to `Application`

Comment: Problem solved. I was not trying it inside the scope of a method (It was never inside the MainWindow as in my example). Arrrggg. :S